# Shift each row in dataframe increasingly to the right

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I would like to have a dataframe like this for example:

```
example=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), b=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), c=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), d = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))

  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8
```

Be transformed so that the first row stays in the same position, but each row after that shifts one column to the right from the previous row, for example:

```
   a  b  c  d  X X.1 X.2 X.3 X.4 X.5 X.6
1  1  1  1  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2 NA  2  2  2  2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3 NA NA  3  3  3   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4 NA NA NA  4  4   4   4  NA  NA  NA  NA
5 NA NA NA NA  5   5   5   5  NA  NA  NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA   6   6   6   6  NA  NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA  NA   7   7   7   7  NA
8 NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA   8   8   8   8
```

This is for the purpose that each column can then be summed (by which I mean that for each new column, the rows will be added together, but there's no meaning to the column titles so moving them doesn't matter), so the column names don't particularly matter.

Any help would be much appreciated as i've yet to stumble across anything to achieve this kind of data transformation.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who answered, all the solutions worked great!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "_This is for the purpose that each column can then be summed_". I'm just curious, because there might be alternative routes to your desired goal. Cheers.

Comment: Better to use a matrix here than a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another base R for loop. I construct the matrix first, and then fill it in.

```
# build matrix of missing values
myMat <- matrix(NA, nrow(example), ncol(example) + nrow(example) - 1)

# fill it in by row with vector pulled from row of example and simiplified with `unlist`
for(i in seq_len(nrow(myMat))) {
  myMat[i, i:(ncol(example) + i - 1)] <- unlist(example[i,], use.names=FALSE)
}
```

This returns

```
myMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]    1    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
[2,]   NA    2    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3    3    3    3   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    4    4    4    4   NA   NA    NA    NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    5    5    5    5   NA    NA    NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    6    6    6    6    NA    NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    7    7    7     7    NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    8    8     8     8
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to create a matrix with NA and fill in the values you want.

```
Shifted = matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(example), 
    ncol=nrow(example) + ncol(example) - 1)
for(i in 1:nrow(example)) {
    Shifted[i, i:(i+ncol(example)-1)] = unlist(example[i,]) }
```

If you really want a data.frame, you can finish off with

```
as.data.frame(Shifted)
```